# Divide two large numbers as strings without using Bignumbers in java

Tags: java, algorithm, math, division, biginteger

I need to divide two large integers WITHOUT using Biginteger since the Numbers can't be stored inside a primitive type  , since I need to do it char by char from the strings I am given,I have already created a class called BigNumber, with this class I can:

1. Add
2. multiply
3. compare two strings with large integers inside

Now I only need to implement the Dividing method but I can't get my head around how to do it with two strings instead of one String and an Int, here's what I got so far, it works if the number we are dividing the String by is small enough to be an int

```
class BigNumber {
    String Number;
BigNumber div(BigNumber other) {
        String result= "";
        String num1= this.Number;
        long Divisor = Integer.parseInt(other.Number);
        int index = 0;
        long NumTemp = num1.charAt(index)-'0';
        while (NumTemp < Divisor){
            NumTemp = NumTemp * 10 +(num1.charAt(index+1) - '0');
            index++;
        }
        while (num1.length()-1 > index){
            result += (NumTemp/Divisor) ;
            NumTemp = (NumTemp % Divisor) * 10 + num1.charAt(index+1) - '0';
            index++;
        }
        result += (NumTemp/Divisor);
        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println(NumTemp);
        BigNumber Big = new BigNumber(result);
        return Big;
    }
}
`
```

PS: My class can also subtract one large number to another, if that helps with the division

Comment: I don't get why you need to use chars and not BigIntegers...

Comment: Why can't you use `BigInteger`? That's class purpose is exaclty that stuff?

Comment: You are doing decimal arithmetic, so shift the divisor by adding zeroes and subtract. Repeat on the remainder.

Comment: So they're not signed?

Comment: They're not signed yes, and I need to do it without BigIntegers because that's the way I was asked to do it

Comment: @stark That sounds interesting, could you maybe try to give me an example with some code please?

Comment: Take a pencil and paper and two largeish numbers, maybe `3456` and `93876`.  Using the method for long division you were taught in school divide the former into the latter.  Pay careful attention to the algorithm you use, in fact pay such careful attention you can write down each individual step you take.  *Voila*

Comment: Your `BigNumber` class would be greatly simplified by storing the number as an array of `int` (or `byte`) instead of as a `String`.  Using `charAt(...)-‘0’` at every step is inefficient, and complicating your algorithms.

Comment: Thank you! @HighPerformanceMark I will try to make it first by hand and implementing the algorithm into my code, @AJNeufeld I am given strings with a test, that's why I have to do it this way, but don't worry I have a method that stores the string in a Char array, so I don't have to use `-'0'` each time, this is just the unclean code for my division method, I just need to make it work and I will clean everything

Comment: The only problem I have when trying to implement the long division method is that my numbers are strings and also I'm working with objects, sorry I'm just lost right now

Comment: How do you find out how many times `3456` goes into `93876` ?  First you take the first 4 digits of `93876`, i.e. `9387` and see if that is greater than `3456` (you've told us you can already compare two *string-integers*).  It is.  How many times ?  Once for sure.  Try twice (you've told us you can do multiplications).  If it goes twice, try thrice.  This time it fails, so you backtrack to twice and subtract (don't forget that subtraction is a kind of addition and you can already do that) `2*3456` from `9387`.  And so on ...

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I will give it a shot and post the result if I get it

Comment: *** I will post the solution when I get it, because I'm not giving up, if it is possible I can do it

Answer (score 2):

I tried what you all told me this morning and got it, thank you all, if you've some improvement over it please tell me, since this is just the rough code without cleaning the inefficiencies, thank you all

```
BigNumber div(BigNumber other) {
            String result = "";
            String num1 = this.Number;
            String num2 = other.Number;
            int Select = num2.length();
            String temp = num1.substring(0, Select);
            BigNumber tempNum = new BigNumber(temp);
            int NumbersLeft = num1.length() - temp.length();
            BigNumber MultObject = new BigNumber("1");
            if (tempNum.compareTo(other) < 0) {
                temp = num1.substring(0, Select+1);
                tempNum.Number = temp;
                NumbersLeft--;
                Select++;
            }
            do {
                MultObject.Number = "0";
                int Index = 0;
                while (other.mult(MultObject).compareTo(tempNum) < 0) {
                    Index++;
                    MultObject.Number = Integer.toString(Index);
                }
                Index--;
                MultObject.Number = Integer.toString(Index);
                String Carry = tempNum.sub(other.mult(MultObject)).Number;
                if (NumbersLeft > 0) {
                    Select++;
                    Carry += num1.charAt(Select - 1);
                    NumbersLeft--;
                }
                result += Index;
                tempNum.Number = Carry;
            }while (NumbersLeft > 0);
            MultObject.Number = "0";
            int Index = 0;
            while (other.mult(MultObject).compareTo(tempNum) < 0) {
                Index++;
                MultObject.Number = Integer.toString(Index);
            }
            Index--;
            MultObject.Number = Integer.toString(Index);
            String Carry = tempNum.sub(other.mult(MultObject)).Number;
            if (NumbersLeft > 0) {
                Select++;
                Carry += num1.charAt(Select - 1);
                NumbersLeft--;
            }
            result += Index;
            tempNum.Number = Carry;
                BigNumber Big = new BigNumber(result);
                return Big;
            }
```