# Java how to divide very large numbers

Tags: java, numbers, divide

Please tell me how to divide the numbers by the column, but taking into account the fact that the numbers in the method will be transferred by the type String (the number to be divided, the number to which to divide). Because numbers can simply be very huge decimals. The output from the class must be in String format.
(public String devide (String toDevide, String whichDevide)) - starts with that

Comment: [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) or [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) maybe?

Comment: If `BigInteger` is for some reason not applicable, still you can check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48582606/divide-two-large-numbers-as-strings-without-using-bignumbers-in-java

Comment: please be precise with your question. Give a example

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While I disagree that your question is unclear, it is certainly (1) poorly researched (2) too broad for Stack Overflow. Always search and research before asking, please. An effort on your part will almost always be matched by one on ours.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Do I convert very big String to number in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967201/how-do-i-convert-very-big-string-to-number-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `BigInteger` or `BigDecimal` class and make use of their `divide()` method.

Comment: I tried. But when i execute it that happends: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result.
 at java.base/java.math.BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal.java:1722)
 at informatika.Main.D(Main.java:90)
 at informatika.Main.run(Main.java:46)
 at informatika.Informatika.main(Informatika.java:19)
\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1328: The following error occurred while executing this line:
\nbproject\build-impl.xml:948: Java returned: 1

Comment: cos i divide (1/19) and i need to get 100 number after point

Comment: @ОоррЛллл Sounds like  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591206/arithmeticexception-non-terminating-decimal-expansion-no-exact-representable